# Which one is the larger : $20!$ or $2^{60}$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, prime-factorization

Which one is the larger : $20!$ or $2^{60}$ ?

---

I am looking for an elegant way to solve this problem, other than my solution below. Also, solution other than using logarithm that uses the analogous inequalities below.

***My solution:***

Write $20!$ in prime factors and $2^{n}$:

$$ 20! = (2^{2} \cdot 5)(19)(2 \cdot 3^{2})(17)(2^{4})(3 \cdot 5)(2 \cdot 7)(13)(2^{2} \cdot 3)(11)(2 \cdot 5)(3^{2})(2^{3})(7)(2 \cdot 3) (5) (2^{2}) (3) (2) $$
$$ = 2^{18} (5)(19)(3^{2})(17)(3 \cdot 5)(7)(13)(3)(11)(5)(3^{2})(7)( 3) (5) (3) $$

so it is left to compare $2^{42}$ and $(5)(19)(3^{2})(17)(3 \cdot 5)(7)(13)(3)(11)(5)(3^{2})(7)( 3) (5) (3) $.

We write the prime factors nicely as:

$$ 3^{8}5^{4}7^{2}(11) (13)(17)(19) $$
Notice

$(3)(11) > 2^{5}$,

$(13)(5)>2^{6}$,

$(19)(7) >2^{7}$,

$17 > 2^{4}$, so we now focus on

$$3^{7}5^{3}7 = 2187(5^{3})7 > 2048(5^{3})7 = 2^{11}875 >2^{11}512 = 2^{20} $$

So we have that the prime factors is larger than $2^{42}$.

Comment: Since one is about $2.11$ times the other, so you do not have much scope for approximation, and your method of aiming for products just above powers of $2$ is probably about as good as it gets

Comment: @Henry "Since one is about $2.11$ times the other"? what does it mean.

Comment: The inequality $\left(\frac n3\right)^n<n!<\left(\frac n2\right)^n$ is well known, I wonder if we can find an easy way to prove $\left(\frac n{2.5}\right)^n<n!$ which would give $20! > 8^{20}=2^{60}$.

Comment: Yep. $20!^{1/60}\approx 2.02,$ so you are probably going to this kind of term-by-term approximation. Stirling’s approximation gives you wanting $$(40\pi)^{1/30}(20/e)^{1/3}>2.$$ But then you’ll also need to know the error function estimates for Stirling.

Comment: Arf, my idea is valid only up to $n=32$ too bad.

Comment: @Redsbefall It means $\dfrac{20!}{2^{60}}\approx \dfrac{2.432902\times 10^{18}}{1.152922\times 10^{18}} \approx 2.11$

Comment: @zwim that won't be true in general, since $n! \approx (n/e)^n$ (that's a very loose approximation, of course)

Comment: I've dropped an answer for the much closer inequality stated some moments after this one here... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482278/which-one-is-the-larger-19-cdot-19-or-261/4482400#4482400 That question is closed now...

Answer (score 1):

$$20!=2^{18}\cdot3^8\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^2\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19$$

$$19\cdot 17\cdot 13=4199>2^{12}, \\3\cdot 11>2^5$$

So it suffices to show:

$$3^7\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^2>2^{25}.$$

Now, $5\cdot 7>2^5,$ and $3^2>2^3,$ so it suffices to showing:

$$75=3\cdot 5^2>2^{6}=64$$

This shows: $$\frac{20!}{2^{60}}=\left(1+\frac{103}{4096}\right)
\left(1+\frac1{32}\right)\left(1+\frac3{32}\right)^2\left(1+\frac18\right)^3\left(1+\frac{11}{64}\right)$$

Comment: There are other inequalities we could have used. In general $(n+k)(n-k)(n+1)>n^4$ for $k^2+1<n.$ Tht explains $(16-3)(16+3)(16+1)>16^3$ and we likewise get $3^4\cdot 7=(8+1)^2(8-1)>8^3.$

Comment: Is not this the same as my solution?

Comment: Well. It is similar, but simpler and using different inequalities. And better formatted. For example, you just use $17\geq 16.$ If I had done that, I wouldn’t be able to use $19\cdot17\cdot 13>16^3.$ @Redsbefall

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends the comment of zwim.

First, see
[Stirling approximation For factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

I know that as $n$ goes to $\infty$, that the geometric mean of
$\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ approaches $~\displaystyle \frac{n}{e}~$ from above.  Further, as $n$ increases, the ratio between $n$ and the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is strictly decreasing.

I also know, from involvement with a prior (similar) problem involving $(100)!$, that even with the number as large as $(100)$, the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ is still greater than $(40)$.

This implies that since $(20) < (100)$, the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,20\}$ must be greater than $~(20 \times 0.4).~$

This surmise makes it *game over*, because $2^{60} = 8^{20}$.  Therefore, since the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,20\}$ is greater than $(8)$, you must have that $(20)! > 8^{20}.$

Comment: How were you planning to find the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,20\}$ or up to $100$ without using factorials or logarithms?

Comment: @Henry I don't know of any way of attacking the problem without using factorials and/or logarithms.  In fact, it was just luck that I could attack the problem without logarithms, simply by convenient comparison of $(2)^{60}$ and $(8)^{20}.$  Further, it was only by chance that I happened to know that the geometric mean of $\{1,2,\cdots,100\}$ was (still) greater than $(40)$.  Without that knowledge, I could not attack the problem.

Comment: Why are you putting all your integers in parentheses? It's so unusual that I feel it must mean something significant, but I can't see what.

Comment: @TonyK Horses for courses.  Others have also mentioned this tendency.  To experienced Math readers, it is a minor annoyance.  To beginning Math students, it is often helpful, because it allows them to *glide* through the text, without misunderstanding anything, or having to pause for reflection.  My target audience is almost always the beginning Math student, with the idea that everyone else will still be able to understand my writing.

Comment: @user2661923: that is delusional.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go for the solution using only elementary computations.
(And building partial products that get bigger than and closer to powers of two. I wanted to use first very close approximations like $3\cdot 18\cdot 19=1026>1024$, but there is no need to be so economical at the beginning, and very generous at the end...)
$$
\begin{aligned}
3\cdot 12 &= 36 \\
&> 32 =2 ^5\ ,\\
5\cdot 13 &= 65 \\
&> 64 =2 ^6\ ,\\
6\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot 11 &= 6\cdot 11\cdot 7\cdot 9 
=66\cdot 63=(64+2)(64-1)=64^2 +64-2
\\
&> 64^2 = (2^8)^2=2^{12}\ ,
\\
15\cdot 17\cdot 14\cdot 19
&=
(256-1)(16-2)(16+3)=
(256-1)(256+16-6)
\\
&>(256-1)(256+2)=256^2 + 256-2\\
&>256^2=(2^8)^2=2^{16}\ ,
\\
10\cdot 18\cdot 20 &= 3600
\\
&>2048=2^{11}\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\text{Putting all together:}
\\[3mm]
20!
&=2\cdot 4\cdot 8\cdot 16
\cdot(3\cdot 12)
\cdot(5\cdot 13)
\cdot(6\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot 11)
\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad
\cdot(14\cdot 15\cdot 17\cdot 19)
\cdot(10\cdot 18\cdot 20)
\\
&>2^{\displaystyle1+2+3+4+5+6+12+16+11} 
\\
&= 2^{\displaystyle60}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$